# Elegant method to show $[L^2,[L^2,\vec{r}\,]\,] = 2\hbar^2\{L^2, \vec{r}\}.$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

Show that $[L^2,[L^2,\vec{r}\,]\,] = 2\hbar^2\{L^2, \vec{r}\},$ where $\vec{r} = x\, {\hat x} + y\, {\hat y} + z\, {\hat z}.$

"Edit: $\{A,B\} = AB + BA$ is the anti-commutator."

I am able to solve this by brute force expanding everything, but I was wondering if there is a quicker, more elegant way of doing so.  Also, if anyone has any physical intuition behind what this result means, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tricky operator identity: $[L^2,[L^2,\vec{r}]]=2 \hbar ^2 \{ L^2, \vec{r}\}$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95264/)